# c# Collection of Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, series

how would I create and then access a collection of a (Sorted)Dictionary?
It could be a `Series<SortedDictionary<double, MyClass>>` or a `Dictionary<int, SortedDictionary<double, MyClass>>` for example.

```
Series[0] = sortedDict;
Dict.Add(myInt, sortedDict);
```

For some reason, when doing it like this, the Dictionary is empty, when accessing values with a loop and the series seems to be empty as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Dict.Count; i++)
{
   SortedDictionary<double, MyClass> sortedDictPair = Dict.ElementAt(i).Value;
   foreach (var item in sortedDictPair)
   {
        Print(item.Key);
        MyClass myClass= item.Value;
        Print(myClass.classMember);
    }
}

SortedDictionary<double, MyClass> sortedDictPair = Series[0];
for (int j = 0; j < sortedDictPair.Count; j++)
    {
        MyClass myClass = sortedDictPair.ElementAt(j).Value;
        Print(myClass.classMember);
    }
 }
```

Is there something I am overseeing?
Edit: when I let it print the sortedDict before aissgning it, it is full of entries.

Comment: You are not adding the sorted dictionary to the parent dictionary.

Comment: Have you added some items inside your sorted dictionary before assigning to Series?

Comment: Right, I forgot to write this here but in my code I have the Dict.Add() I edited the post. Yes the SortedDictionary is full of entries when I assign it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try them in two foreach loops?

```
Dictionary<int, SortedDictionary<double, MyClass>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, SortedDictionary<double, MyClass>>()
    {
        { 1, new SortedDictionary<double,MyClass>(){ {2, new MyClass{ Score=1 } }, { 3, new MyClass { Score = 1 } } } },
        { 2, new SortedDictionary<double,MyClass>()}
    };
    foreach (var item1 in dictionary)
    {
        foreach (var item2 in item1.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item2.Key);
            MyClass myClass = item2.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(myClass.Score);
        }
    }
```

[image: Check]

Comment: The result is the same. It prints just "" (nothing). While when I let it print the SortedDict before assigning it to the Dict or Series, it prints a bunch of lines

Comment: Please run my code and see its printing the SortedDictionary

Comment: Jesus! Thank you man! Finally, I found my mistake. I forgot that a dictionary is a reference type and I cleared it always after assigning it, thinking it would transfer the values and keep them transferred. But since its a reference type it doesn't. Was valuable to see this example.

Comment: your welcome, happy you fixed your issue